# mongoose remove nested object inside an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nested, mongoose-schema

Im trying to remove a nested object from an array by the _id property, however I wasnt able to make it work and other posts here were of no help either, my db look something like this:

```
storage:Array
    0:Object
        folders:Array
            0:Object
                stored:Array
                    0:Object
                        files:Object
                            name:"1"
                            snippet:"snippet 1"
                            _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd822
                    1:Object
                        files:Object
                            name:"2"
                            snippet:"snippet 2"
                            _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd823
                    2:Object
                        files:Object
                            name:"3"
                            snippet:"snippet 3"
                            _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd824
                    3:Object
                        files:Object
                            name:"4"
                            snippet:"snippet 4"
                            _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd825
                    4:Object
                        files:Object
                            name:"5"
                            snippet:"snippet 5"
                            _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd826
                    5:Object
                        files:Object
                            name:"6"
                            snippet:"snippet 6"
                            _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd827
                    6:Object
                        folders:Object
                            name:"indented folder"
                            _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd828
                            stored:Array
                                0:Object
                                    files:Object
                                        name:"indented file 1"
                                        snippet:"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blandit..."
                                        _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd829
                        _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd82a
                name:"test"
                _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd821
        files:Array
            0:Object
                name:"message"
                snippet:"Hello World!"
                _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd82b
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$pull**, something like :-

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(_id,{
    $pull: {
        arrayKeyName: {_id: _idOfObjectInArray}
    }
}, {new: true});
```

Comment: `User.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{
            $pull: {
                storage: {_id: id}
            }
        }, {new: true});`
Ive tried something like this (no clue if this is correct), but it does not work, is there a chance this doesnt work on embedded objects? I can only find the object by the _id property and sadly dont know in whihc array it will be